# Image is cut in the inside of the block

Tags: html, css

It is necessary that the image went beyond the block `.column`, not cutting.

Image 850px

.column 225px

Image should load fully

**How to make so that the picture is loaded completely?**

The project is large, but the layout is such:

```css
.content { display: inline-block; }
.column {float:right; width:225px;}

.slider {
  width: auto;
  max-width: inherit;
}

.slider img {
  width: auto;
  max-width: inherit !important;
  max-height: inherit !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">  
    <div class="column">
      <div class="slider">
        <div><img src='https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/2c/d0/19/2cd0197c5eb8c1f84e81734f97e80cd3.jpg' /></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

This happened after installing the [slick](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) slider . Before this behavior was normal.

Comment: Set your image to 100% width.

Comment: I'm probably wrong) if I do `width: 100%;` then the picture will fill the block 220px, and I want the image (850px) filled block 220px. I want a full size picture

Comment: now I need to override a rule for pictures

Comment: Do you mean you want the image to flow over , outside of <div class="slider">?

Comment: outside of `.content` & `.column`

Comment: I have a hard time understanding your question and I have to go to sleep, but if I guess right, you are looking for "overflow:visible;". Set the overflow to visible on .content and .column

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is what you are looking for.

```
.content .column {overflow:visible;}
```